# Configure Maven to allow a range of JREs

Tags: java, maven

I am teaching a 2nd semester Java course, and I am trying to set up a *simple* Maven project that will will run in any student's environment (Windows/Mac/Linux, IntelliJ/VS Code/Eclipse,  any version of Java 8 or above) without complaining. Because this is only a second semester programming course, I want `pom.xml` to be as simple as possible.  The project need only be a couple of Java source files and a couple of test files.

The current `pom.xml` is below.  It works, but Visual Studio Code on MacOS with Java 8 generates the following warnings:

- Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.5. There are no
  JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with
  this environment.
- The compiler compliance specified is 1.5 but a JRE
  1.8 is used

I can fix the problem by adding these lines:

```
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
```

But, won't that cause warnings or errors for students with different Java versions? Since we aren't doing anything fancy, I don't want to require that they all use Java 12 or 13.  Any version 8 or above is fine.

I also hesitate to tell the students to edit the properties above to match their machines because I assume that will cause problems if I pull their code and try to run it on my machine.

Is there a way to configure Maven and the IDE to simply be happy with any JDK version 8 and above?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>gvsucis</groupId>
  <artifactId>ArrayLab</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ArrayLab</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Setting the compiler target  and source is what you want here just like you are doing it. Setting to Java 8 (Java 11 is the new lts version btw) should be fine, and will not prevent students from using versions 8+, thanks to Java backwards compatibility

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish between the JDK and the Java version you build for.

Setting `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target` only sets the target Java version. If you set it to `1.8`, then you can build with any JDK that supports this, which are JDK 8 and above.

Comment: That makes sense.  But, then, why am I getting warnings about potential incompatibilities with 1.5?  If Java is generally backwards compatible, when wouldn't the default 1.5 settings be fine given the 1.8 installed on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

Please change your java home to use `jdk` not `jre`.

if you are using a jdk8+, then your pom configuration should work.

Typically all IDE refer the JAVA_HOME environment variable to find the `java` binary. So, Set your `JAVA_HOME` to `jdk8+`.

if it is widows machine restart is required otherwise just run `source .bashrc` or `source .bach_profile`